# Что не так в cors ajax get запросе?

Tags: ajax, cors

Пытаюсь найти элемент который успешно загружается.
Ругается на .find()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var geturl = 'https://game-shop.com.ua/product/mass-effect-andromeda-ps4-russkaya-versiya';
  $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
      var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
      options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
      //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
    }
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    $.get(geturl, function(data, status) {
      $('body').html(data);
      alert('Status: ' + status);
    });
    $('body').css('background', 'red');
    $('body').prepend('<a href="#">qwe</a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SimpleGrabber</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>GET</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы пишете что все успешно загружается, при этом ругается на `find`, который к `cors` никак не относится. Уточните вопрос и укажите желаемое поведение примера.

Comment: Я выгружаю другую страницу к себе в body.
Теперь хочу найти все элементы внутри это го же body кроме тех что с классом .my3(и все его наследники) и удалить их.

Comment: Ну так укажите пример (10-15 строк) содержимого `body` которое получаете , и как должно быть.

Comment: Заменил код, смотрите.
Пытаюсь по выполнению покрасить body и добавить кнопку, а он сразу это делает, не дожидаясь полной загрузки содержимого data.
И скажите же, как обратиться к определенному элементу, который загрузился в body ?

Comment: Тип полученных данных (string), только что проверил, почему же find не работает тогда?

Comment: ajax запрос подразумевает асинхронную подгрузку, т.е. работает параллельно. Нужно подождать немного времени пока `jquery` добавит страницу в боди после запроса, например оберните в таймаут 2 строки с изменение цвета и добавления ссылки, так: `setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').css('background', 'red');
      $('body').prepend('<a href="#">qwe</a>');
    }, 10000);`

Comment: Хорошо, это от части помогло.
Теперь другая беда: хочу после загрузки удалить все элементы, роме текущего и еще одного по классу. вот так:
`setTimeout(function(){ 
   var reslt = $('body').not(this).not('div.single-wrapper').filter('*').remove();
  }, 10000);`